# Fourier Transform of a Wave Packet

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions, fourier-transform, geometric-optics

In the analysis of coherence and interference, I encountered the following expression:
$$F(t)=\Re\int_0^\infty\mathrm d\omega e^{-i\omega t}H(\omega)$$, where $\Re$ denotes the real part of the integral, and $H(\omega)$ vanishes for $\omega<0$.
I want to show the Fourier transform of $F(t)$ is
$$\hat{F}(t)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi}}{2}[H(\omega)+H^\star(-\omega)]$$
Here is my approach
$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm d\omega e^{-i\omega t}H(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm d\omega e^{-i\omega t}H(\omega)=\sqrt{2\pi}H(t)$$
where $H(t)$ is the Fourier transform of $H(\omega)$ (with out the hat), and I used the fact $H(\omega)=0$ for $\omega<0$. Hence
$$F(t)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi}}{2}[H(t)+H^\star(t)]$$
It follows that
$$\hat F(t)=\frac{\sqrt {2\pi}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm d\omega e^{-i\omega t}[H(t)+H^\star(t)]=\pi[H(\omega)+H^\star(-\omega)]$$
Although the form of my result agree with the correct answer, I got a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ wrong somewhere. I wonder where did I miss it!

Comment: It's not just a normalization/convention issue?

Comment: I think so, but in the book the normalization for the transform is always chosen to be $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$, so there is an inconsistency, and I probably done something wrong...

Answer (score 3):

Mathematicians usually put $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ before each integral.  Physicists usually leave it out of the integral like your first equation, but then divide the inverse integral by $2\pi$